# Need help for an exercise for school, and I cant figure out why doesn't SUM work here

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
SELECT 
    F.numero, 
    SUM (SELECT (C.unidades * P.preco)
         FROM linhafatura C, produto P)
         WHERE (C.produto = P.ean13)
           AND (C.produto = L.produto)
           AND (C.fatura = L.fatura))
FROM fatura F, linhafatura L
WHERE (F.numero = L.fatura);
```

I tested it in SQL live and it just says

> ORA-00936: missing expression

which is a really helpful error

(I am sure the tables and data introduced are all correct because the code was made by my teachers)

Any help is accepted, thanks

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Is the problem the syntax style or is it just a side note? Cuz this is how they are teaching me mostly, we just haven't using the sum function in class yet so there aren't any examples for me to understand it

Comment: **Gosh** - how horrible that there are *still* schools teaching this old, long-time deprecated style .... try to get into the habit of **NOT** using that anymore!! It's been 30 years since it's been replaced by **proper ANSI JOINs** .....

Answer (score 0):

Your query extra closing bracket after `FROM linhafatura C, produto P)` and you need to wrap the correlated sub-query inside `()` brackets so you have one set of brackets for the `SUM()` function and another for the sub-query and you also need a `GROUP BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT F.numero, 
       SUM(
         (
           SELECT (C.unidades * P.preco)
           FROM   linhafatura C, produto P
           WHERE  (C.produto = P.ean13)
           AND    (C.produto = L.produto)
           AND    (C.fatura = L.fatura)
         )
       ) AS value
FROM   fatura F,
       linhafatura L
WHERE  (F.numero = L.fatura)
GROUP BY
       f.numero;
```

Which can be rewritten without the additional brackets as:

```sql
SELECT F.numero, 
       SUM(
         (
           SELECT C.unidades * P.preco
           FROM   linhafatura C, produto P
           WHERE  C.produto = P.ean13
           AND    C.produto = L.produto
           AND    C.fatura = L.fatura
         )
       ) AS value
FROM   fatura F,
       linhafatura L
WHERE  F.numero = L.fatura
GROUP BY
       f.numero;
```

and again, rewritten with modern ANSI joins (rather than the legacy comma-join syntax from 30 years ago):

```sql
SELECT F.numero, 
       SUM (
         (
           SELECT C.unidades * P.preco
           FROM   linhafatura C
                  INNER JOIN produto P
                  ON C.produto = P.ean13
           WHERE  C.produto = L.produto
           AND    C.fatura = L.fatura
         )
       ) AS value
FROM   fatura F
       INNER JOIN linhafatura L
       ON F.numero = L.fatura
GROUP BY
       f.numero;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/U8H7zJ_-)

*Note: depending on your data you may get the error: `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row` [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/x3R46T1s)*

Comment: So I pasted your solutions in sql live and it gives me the same error, it's probably the website's fault, do you know any other website I can test the code?

Comment: @OKCupid200069 My queries should not have given a `Missing Expression` exception. However, I did need to add a `GROUP BY` clause, which I've edited in. I've also added a link to a working fiddle.

Comment: Thx, i was missing the GROUP BY part, it works fine now